# Is this way of texturing supported in Direct3d?

Tags: arrays, textures, direct3d

At the moment, I am trying to create a texture programatically in the following fashion:
I have a 1 dimensional array of hexadecimals:

```
      char array = { 0xfe, 0xfd, 0xfb, 0xf7, 0xef, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0x7f }
```

and I want to create this texture using *the bits* that make up this array since F = 1111 and 7 = 0111 in binary and so on. Visually, it would look like this:

```
    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
    1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
    1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
    1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
    1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1
    1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
    0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Essentially, each element of the array would represent a row, and each of the eight bits that make up one of the characters would represent the elements. 0's would stand for *not filled* and 1's for "filled". I would then apply color to it depending on some outside mechanism. I found on MSDN this DXGI_format:

```
    DXGI_FORMAT_R1_UNORM
```

which takes in one bit, so I am guessing something similar to this procedure is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 1-bit format supported by Direct3D. The `DXGI_FORMAT_R1_UNORM` format was created for some early GDI font support in the Direct3D 10 era, but the format itself is not supported for texturing by any Direct3D hardware.

About the smallest format you can find is going to be `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` where you'd expand your 1s to a 255 byte and keep your 0s as a 0 byte.

> For a bunch of code dealing with raw pixel formats, take a look at [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex). There's some code there for expanding monochrome formats like `DXGI_FORMAT_R1_UNORM` in the [Convert](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/DirectXTexConvert.cpp) codebase.